# How to correctly validate a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm getting confused when it comes to model validation.

What I've done for 6 different algorithms:

-->separated my dataset 75/25 (training/test) --> the test I left untouched.

-->with the training set I did the following:

1. splited in 4-folds (outer) and performed a nested repeated (five times) tenfold (inner) cross-validation. With hiperparameter tuning by random search 10 times. (leave one out strategy)
2. extracted the metrics (ROC curves, acc, specificity, etc) and got the parameters of the best model.

Now this is the problem:

I still have an untouched test set (from the split in the beginning), what should I do with it? Apply directly to the best model and see the performance? or retrain the best model with the best parameters using the whole training set and then apply the test set?

Or is everything wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it. This is the general rule:

- Pick the best model out of the 6. I see that K is 4 in your case, recommended is 10 or 20.
- Retrain the best model again on all parts together (Entire training set). (Trust is already established from cross validation).
- Predict on test set.

Comment: to put this info in an article, should I say that I validated the model using the nested CV and picked the best model to test it's performance in a new untouched test set ? I think I'm choosing poorly the words when explaining what i've done.